# Нужно добавить класс к элементу из списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток,
Помогите разобраться.
Как сделать что бы при открытии вкладки аккордеона,к `i` которая находится во вкладке добавлялся класс `i_transform`?Как ни делал он добавлялся ко всем i находящимся в списке.

[Код аккордеона тут](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/15286/).

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/15370/

```
thisChildI = $this.find('i');
   if (thisChildI.hasClass('i_transform')) {
      thisChildI.removeClass('i_transform');
   } else {
      thisChildI.addClass('i_transform');
   }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь ;)